# Как стилизовать отдельные слова в поле ввода textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Допустим пользователь вводит текст в textarea - "I have no" и как только он вводит "I have no #money" тег должен быть выделен каким-то стилем, а весь остальной текст остаться классическим.
Вот регулярное выражение которым можно распознать тег:

```
/#[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]+\b/g
```

Возможно ли реализовать такую функцию и если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const text = document.querySelector('textarea');
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');

text.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let string = this.value;
  let array = string.split(/(\s+)/);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].includes('#')) {
      array[i] = "<span class='highlight'>" + array[i] + "</span>";
    }
  }
  string = array.join('');

  pre.innerHTML = string;
});
```

```css
.textarea {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.textarea textarea {
  resize: none;
  z-index: 1;
  caret-color: white;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.textarea textarea,
.textarea pre {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.textarea pre {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea">
  <textarea rows='5' cols='50'></textarea>
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Как сделать чтобы был перенос слов. pre почему то неограничен широтой, а хотелось бы что бы его ширина была как и у textarea...

Comment: @Lil_Chill исправил)

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2):

В textarea никак нельзя, но легко можно сделать собственное решение. Вот так например:

```js
const highlighted = /#[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]+/g;

editor.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  view.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(highlighted, function(text) {
    return '<span class="highlighted">' + text + '</span>';
  });
});

editor.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  view.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  view.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
});
```

```css
#editor,
#view {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#editor {
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: black;
}

#view {
  color: black;
}

span.highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="view" class="original"></div>
```